# QuickBox2D: Pixelated Skin

Tags: actionscript-3, compression, png

this strange problem is ocurring to me.

I have one png image (lossless) turned into movieClip, when I call it on the scene, it becomes extremely pixelated, other images on stage have the same treatment and don't show pixelization.

[image: Normal Image]

[image: Bitmap Propierties]

[image: Pixelated Movieclip]

**This is how I call it:**
Note: QuickBox2D Lib works in meters (1 meter = 30 pixels)

```
sim.addBox({x:0/30,y:300/30, width:600/30, height:28/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
```

Comment: Not enough code. Maybe you create the `QuickBox2D` object with `debug` mode or `simpleRender` enabled/disabled? Try if it works in the normal Box2D, without the quickbox wrapper.

Comment: The last time I had a pixelation problem, was when I used the rotateY propery of one of my movie clips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem in the skin itself, I was calling an old skin without noticing. I needed to replace "stick" with "bigStick", I can't believe it didn't notice!